# Appharbor deploy with multiple unit testing projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, appharbor, multiple-projects

I have an app hosted on appharbor with multiple Unit Test projects (a project per layer) but appharbor only runs one test projects any idea why it does this and how to make it run all my tests

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was my fault as I named the assembly of all the test project by one name so the build overwritten each other and one test project only was built and ran